# Single command codeception & Symfony tests?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, codeception

An application with existing `WebTestCase` functional tests in a bundle has some codeception acceptance tests added.  It would be nice to run, for example, a code coverage command that would include both sets of tests.  Is this possible?  For a starter, here's a `functional.suite.yml` that throws no error on `codecept run functional` but also says

> No tests executed!

#### functional.suite.yml

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Functional
        - Asserts
        - Db:
            dsn: 'sqlite:./app/cache/test/test.sqlite'
            user: ''
            password: ''
            dump: tests/_data/test.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: true
            reconnect: true
        - Symfony2:
            app_path: ./app
            var_path: ./app
            environment: test
    groups:
        symfony:
            - ../src/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/AdminControllerTest.php
```

#### AdminControllerTest excerpt

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

/**
 *
 * @group symfony
 *
 */
class AdminControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
...
}
```